# How to install full node setup for Cardano (ada) coin

Tags: node.js, installation, blockchain, cardano

I'm setting up a full node instance on my aws server for Cardano (ada), but cardano documents display a popup that this document is not fully updated. Can anyone help how to install full node on my server.
How to use json RPC calls to access this ada blockchain in testnet or mainnet. Because the example-

```
*curl -X POST https://localhost:8090/api/v1/wallets \
  -H "Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  --cert ./scripts/tls-files/client.pem \
  --cacert ./scripts/tls-files/ca.crt \
  -d '{
  "operation": "create",
  "backupPhrase": ["squirrel","material","silly","twice","direct","slush","pistol","razor","become","junk","kingdom","flee"],
  "assuranceLevel": "normal",
  "name": "MyFirstWallet",
  "spendingPassword": "5416b2988745725998907addf4613c9b0764f04959030e1b81c603b920a115d0"
}'*
```

in ada documentation used certificate verifications. Can anyone help how it can be implemented in nodejs.

I have already installed Daedalus wallet, nix.